# Foreign key on same table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have a db schema that includes

```
Group{name, group.id, parent.id} with key {group.id}
```

In this schema all **parent.id**'s must either already exist in the **group.id** column or be null.
How can i translate this constraint into `SQL` while creating the table?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular foreign key should suffice. It won't perform any checks if the field is null. The precise syntax may depend slightly on the SQL dialect, but it would look something like

```
create table Group_ (
    name varchar(30) not null,
    groupid int not null primary key,
    parentid int null foreign key references Group_ (groupid) )
```